How to boot ubuntu live usb but ignoring existing disks?
A recent 20.4 update wrecked my system, and I want to boot a live USB to do repairs.
But when I boot the current (24.04) live USB, it is asking me all sorts of questions about Installing, and the setup of my current raids and LVM.
I do NOT want it to install, and I don't want it to touch my disks. How can I do that?
